# Proof: There is no other prime triple then 3,5,7

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

**Proof: There is no other prime triple then $3,5,7$**

There are already lots of questions about this proof, but I can't find the answer to my question.

The complete the proof, we consider mod $3$ so $p=3k; p=3k+1; p=3k+2$

But why do we look at divisibility by $3$?

Do we look at mod $4$ for prime quads?

Comment: You look at divisibility by $3$ because you have some number theory intuition based on experience. Since the difference, $2$, is relatively prime to $3$ a sequence three long will have every possible value mod $3$.

Comment: @EthanBolker Do we look at mod 4 for prime quads?

Comment: Since there are no prime triples there can't be any prime quads.

Comment: "But why do we look at divisibility by 3?" because it works. "Do we look at mod 4 for prime quads?" no. We look at the fact that every prime quad contains a prime triple

Comment: [You](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/503282/elce?tab=questions)  are great at not accepting answers. Which is a good thing, if you don't want to return anything for the help you are getting here.

Answer (score 4):

If $p=2$ then we have no solution.

If $p, p+2,p+4$ are primes then exactly one of them is divisible by 3, so it must be $p=3$.

Comment: Do we look at mod 4 for prime quads?

Comment: No mod 3 .........

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: You have 3 consecutive odd numbers so it worth trying mod 3

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
p(p+2)(p+4)
&=p^3+6p^2+8p\\
&=3\left[5\binom{p}{1}+6\binom{p}{2}+2\binom{p}{3}\right]
\end{align}
$$
is divisible by $3$, so unless one of the factors *is* $3$, one of the factors is not prime.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $p,p+2,p+4$ are all prime.

Consider $p+2,p+3,p+4$.  Since these are three consecutive integers, one of them must be divisible by $3$ (that's why we consider divisibility by $3$ and not by some other number).  It can't be $p+2$ or $p+4$ because they are primes and not equal to $3$ (otherwise $p$ would be $1$ or $-1$ which are not primes.  So $3 | p+3$ and therefore $3 | p$. Hence the only such triple is $3,5,7$.